# How to lay out a core java module with an Android GUI layer on top

Tags: java, android, modules, directory-structure

How can I use Java modules in an Android app repository? In particular, what directory structure should I use?

I have a project in mind for which I would like to have a GUI-independent core Java  9 module (which could be distributed independently) and an Android GUI layer on top.

I created a new IntelliJ project using the 'Android > Empty Activity' template, which created an overwhelmingly complicated directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

Where would I put in this directory structure the core module—which could be added, for example, as a git submodule—? At the same level as `app`? E.g.:

[image]

Or within `app/libs`?

Comment: Use a directory structure that organizes your code in a way that makes it easy for you to find things.